# Accessing form values after passport local authentication

Tags: node.js, passport-local

So I have a form where user enters username,login info and select other option such as level of proficiency to access different interfaces. for login, I am using passport-local strategy and everything works fine. I have no whatsoever any problem with login. Everything works as expected.

In order to render appropriate interface, I need to check  the  values in my login route to load the interface after successful login. I dont know how to access those values in /login GET.

Yes, I am passing the body values in done(null,req.body) in my passport login LocalStrategy as [described.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918135)

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
        myuserlistdb.findOne({ email: email, password: password }).then((status) => {
                console.log('Strategy status-->', status);
                if (status == false) return done(null); 
               return done(null, req.body); // <--- here 
            });
        }));
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out

Comment: This all depends on how you remember the logged in user, if you aren't using any sort of token / session data  then authentication is lost on subsequent requests.

Comment: @James I have already solve my problem. I just saved the value in session and accessed it, But thanks anyway :) :)